# How to receive data over Ethernet using LWIP, UDP

Tags: udp, embedded, stm32, ethernet, lwip

I'm trying to send data to and from my computer and an [STM32H745](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h745-755.html) over Ethernet using [LwIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LwIP) and UDP. I have successfully configured the card and right now I can send data from the card to a Python script running on the computer. However, I don't understand how udp_recv works [<udp,lwip>](https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_0_x/group__udp__raw.html) or how to receive data with UDP on LwIP in general, and I can't find examples that do just that. Where is the data being received? Should I even use udp_recv?

In the main loop I run MX_LWIP_Process, which runs ethernetif_input which somehow handles the received data, but I don't understand where it puts it.

Below is the main code, just for reference.

```
const char* message = "a";

HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_1); // orange

ip_addr_t PC_IPADDR;
IP_ADDR4(&PC_IPADDR, 192, 168, 1, 200);

u16_t port = 8000;

struct udp_pcb* my_udp = udp_new();

struct pbuf* udp_buffer = NULL;

/* Infinite loop */
for (;; )
{
    MX_LWIP_Process();
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_1); // orange
    HAL_Delay(1000);

    udp_buffer = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT, strlen(message), PBUF_RAM);
    if (udp_buffer != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(udp_buffer->payload, message, strlen(message));
        udp_sendto(my_udp, udp_buffer,&PC_IPADDR, port);
        pbuf_free(udp_buffer);
    }

    //udp_recv (struct udp_pcb *pcb, udp_recv_fn recv, void *recv_arg)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`udp_recv()` does not actually receive UDP datagrams (despite its name).  It registers a callback function that will then be called by `MX_LWIP_Process()` when a datagram has been buffered.  It would better be called `udp_set_recv_callback()`, but it is what it is.

To that end you should call it once *before* your executive loop:

```
    udp_bind( my_udp, IP_ADDR_ANY, port ) ;
    udp_recv( my_udp, udp_receive_callback, NULL ) ;

    /* Infinite loop */
    for (;; )
    {
         // Run the CubeMX LwIP stack
         MX_LWIP_Process() ;

         ...
    }
```

Where `udp_receive_callback` is a function that will be invoked on receipt of a datagram:

```
void udp_receive_callback( void* arg,              // User argument - udp_recv `arg` parameter
                           struct udp_pcb* upcb,   // Receiving Protocol Control Block
                           struct pbuf* p,         // Pointer to Datagram
                           const ip_addr_t* addr,  // Address of sender
                           u16_t port )            // Sender port 
{

  // Process datagram here (non-blocking code)
  ...
  
  // Must free receive pbuf before return
  pbuf_free(p);
}
```

Examples include:

- https://gist.github.com/iwanbk/1399729
- https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF2/blob/master/Projects/STM322xG_EVAL/Applications/LwIP/LwIP_UDP_Echo_Client/Src/udp_echoclient.c

Documentation can be found at https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_0_x/group__udp__raw.html

Comment: I want to know how to figure out the length of the packet. The examples simply ignore that and send back what was recieved (same length I presume). But to do something useful I need to process the right number of bytes....

Comment: @user242579 your _comment_ on this answer does not relate to this question.  You should post a new question - SO is a Q&A not a discussion forum.  However the information you are looking for is in the `pbuf` structure: http://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_0_x/structpbuf.html.  Advice: read and understand the _documentation_ above needing an example that does _exactly_ what you want.  That is why I included the documentation link.